# Securing an API whilst allowing access to Swagger

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have the following SecurintConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                        .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .addFilterBefore(new ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

and the following ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter:

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String apiKey = request.getHeader("X-API-Key");
        String apiSecret = request.getHeader("X-API-Secret");

        logger.debug("Received API key: {}", apiKey);
        logger.debug("Received API secret: {}", apiSecret);

        if (apiKey == null || apiSecret == null) {
            unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, new BadCredentialsException("Missing API Key or Secret"));
            return;
        }

        // Check if the provided API key and secret are valid using ApiKeyLoader.
        Map<String, ApiCredentials> apiKeys = apiKeyLoader.getApiKeys();
        ApiCredentials apiCredentials = findApiCredentials(apiKeys, apiKey);

        if (apiCredentials == null || !apiCredentials.getSecret().equals(apiSecret)) {
            unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, new BadCredentialsException("Invalid API Key or Secret."));
            return;
        }

        // Authenticate the user with the provided API key and secret.
        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(apiKey, apiSecret, Collections.emptyList());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        logger.info("Authentication successful for API key: {}", apiKey);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("An error occurred during API key authentication", e);
        unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, new BadCredentialsException("Authentication error"));
    }
}
```

Here is the pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <spring-security.version>5.7.0</spring-security.version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId></groupId>
    <artifactId></artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name></name>
    <description>HL7 Base64 report sender utilising OBR segments</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <springdoc.version>2.2.0</springdoc.version>
        <hapi.version.stable>2.3</hapi.version.stable>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Springdoc OpenAPI dependencies (Swagger) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HAPI HL7 FRAMEWORK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>hapi-base</artifactId>
            <version>${hapi.version.stable}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>hapi-structures-v25</artifactId>
            <version>${hapi.version.stable}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>hapi-structures-v24</artifactId>
            <version>${hapi.version.stable}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>hapi-structures-v231</artifactId>
            <version>${hapi.version.stable}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>hapi-structures-v23</artifactId>
            <version>${hapi.version.stable}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>hapi-structures-v22</artifactId>
            <version>${hapi.version.stable}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.49</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <organization>
        <name>Incarta Healthcare</name>
        <url>https://incarta.com.au</url>
    </organization>
</project>
```

However, access to /swagger-ui/ is blocked pending an API Key - which is not what I want. I need swagger to be accessible without the key. Any help or guidance appreciated!

Comment: Can you share your pom/dependency file as well? I would like to know the version (Spring Boot, Swagger) you are using.